# Breaking Cloudinary after Rails 6.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, cloudinary

I upgraded to Rails 6.1, which broke my Cloudinary.

Whenever I go to an instance that has a photo attached, I now get this:

```
undefined method `service_name' for #<ActiveStorage::Blob:0x00007fb4b1c6de88>
Did you mean?  service
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show us more code where `service_name` is defined in your app?

Answer (score 1):

Running `rails active_storage:update` solved my problem.

I had already run `rails app:update`, which created the following migration: `AddForeignKeyConstraintToActiveStorageAttachmentsForBlobId`

But after running `rails active_storage:update` I got two extra migrations:

`AddServiceNameToActiveStorageBlobs`  & `CreateActiveStorageVariantRecords`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to the issue in another [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65499645/undefined-method-service-name-for-activestorageblob-after-upgrading-to-rails).

The accepted answer was to run

```
rails active_storage:update
rails db:migrate
```