# undefined method 'service_name' for ActiveStorage::Blob after upgrading to rails 6.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I upgraded my app from 6.0.3.4 to 6.1.0 and got this error message. Looked it up and didn't find anything.

I have a very basic usage of ActiveStorage

[image: error message]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to create the new upgrade migrations via:

```
rails active_storage:update
```

Comment: Man, would be nice if this was in the upgrade notes here https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-6-0-to-rails-6-1 anyone know how to make that change happen?

Comment: you can raise it as an issue on github.com/rails/rails or make a pull request

Comment: make sure to obviously run `rake db:migrate` after this.

Comment: This works, but my tests was still failing. If you use active storage fixtures as part of your test, you need to add `service_name: test` to it. For example, in `fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml`, add `service_name: test` for each record.

Answer (score 2):

Similar error message going from 6.0.2 -> 6.1.1 for me :

```
Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `service_name'
```

again, the "rails active_storage:update" command fixes this by adding the required attributes to the database tables, but logging here as a search for the above error was returning nothing useful from Google at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little ridiculous, but I had the same error message on heroku (I had already updated ActiveStorage locally and everything was ready to go live).

All that was required was:

```
heroku restart
```

and everything worked as expected.